# Append more than one value in dynamic listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have a doubt in listview android. I am getting 3 dynamic values from service. I am using my own Arraylist Adpater. I have 3 textviews. I am able to get the data from service. I need to know how can i place  the 3 values in individual textview of the listview.

sample code:

```
buddyNameList[i] = r.getName() + status; 
            //buddyNameLists[i] = status;
                //RowData rd;
                for(i=0;i<buddyNameList[i].length();i++){



                //buddyJidList[i] = r.getUser();
                // Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,DataHelper.class);
                // myIntent.putExtra("UJID", mydata);
                // startActivity(myIntent);
                // dh.insertBuddy(r.getUser(),r.getName());
                i++;
                ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.custom_row_view,R.id.name     ,buddyNameList); // here i can append one value in 1 textview. i need to display all 3            //values from service in 3 individual textview in listview

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I need to know how to place values of all 3 data in corresponding cell in listview
Kindly guide me how can i achive the result.

Thanks in advance.
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom BaseAdapter. In the getView of the adapter, inflate your layout and give values for the textViews. Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. we can add many textviews dynamically.

```
String[] name =
    {
        "Apple",
        "Banana",
        "Orange",
        "Mango",
        "Grapes",
        "Jack Fruit",
        "Strawberry",
        "cucumber",
        "pumpkin",
        "pine Apple"
    };
String[] age =
    {
        "20",
        "21",
        "22",
        "23",
        "24",
        "25",
        "26",
        "27",
        "28",
        "29"
    };
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


   TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
    tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    int Fruits_length=name.length;
    int i=0;

    while(i<Fruits_length)
    {


    String str1 = "<font color=#0099ff>Name</font> <br/> <font color=#ffffff> "+name[i]+" </font>";

    String str2="<font color=#0099ff>Age</font> <br/> <font color=#ffffff> "+age[i]+" </font>";


    final TableRow tr=new TableRow(Listview2Activity.this);

        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


             tr.setId(i);



            final TextView b1=new TextView(Listview2Activity.this);
               b1.setTextSize(15);
               b1.setText(Html.fromHtml(str1));
               b1.setWidth(200);
            tr.addView(b1);

            final TextView b2=new TextView(Listview2Activity.this);
            b2.setTextSize(15);
            b2.setText(Html.fromHtml(str2));
            b2.setWidth(200);
         tr.addView(b2);


             tr.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape));
           tv.addView(tr);


        final View vline1 = new View(Listview2Activity.this);
      vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
      vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
      tv.addView(vline1);      


                tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        String e=String.valueOf(tr.getId());

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


                    }
                });

    i=i+1;
    }


}
```

}